# How can I get DataGridView control to my form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I am using Visual Studio 2010 professional to develop an ecommerce website.

I need a data grid, which is Not bound, to which I can add data rows manually. I have tried the Gridview control but it seems to only work with data bound rows.

I have searched the internet and it seems that the DataGridView control will allow me to do this. However, when I add it to the toolbox it is grayed out and I am unable to add it to my form.

I am working in VB, not C#.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

3/2/21 Update
Thanks for the comments so far they actually help me to ask a better question.

I apologize for not being more specific.

I have created a gridview control in me ASP.net web project.
I add a datasource to the asp web page.
When I test the data source in the IDE the datacontrol pulls the data using a stored procedure, from a SQL database and displays it just fine.

However, when I try to test by running the project on my local machine, it does not display any data.

Micrsoft's help files are deplorable. They only give C# examples for one thing.

I do have 5 rows displayed on the gridview and the data usually returns more rows than that. I am assuming the extra rows will be added automatically. Is that my problem?

I am using bound data fields. Should I be using Dynamic fields instead?
The ASPX code is as follows

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" 

Codebehind="AppProdsSelect.aspx.vb"   %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 10pt;
            height: 492px;
            width: 1106px;
        }
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        table
        {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        table th
        {
            background-color: #F7F7F7;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        table th, table td
        {
            padding: 5px;
            border-color: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" submitdisabledcontrols="True">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="54px" ImageUrl="Images/CrescentLogo2007.bmp"  Width="175px" />
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" 
                Text="Call us at 1-800-560-7867" CssClass="style2"></asp:Label>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
                <br />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;

        
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
    <div>


                <asp:Button ID="ButtonMakes" runat="server" Text="Makes" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonModels" runat="server" Text="Models" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonYears" runat="server" Text="Years" />
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonEngines" runat="server" Text="Engines" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="View Shopping Cart" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Items in Cart:" Width="128px"></asp:Label>
    </div>


                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1080px" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Height="169px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product" HeaderText="Product" 
                            SortExpression="Product" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product Code" DataField="ProductCode" 
                            ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AppQualifier" DataField="AppQualifier" 
                            SortExpression="AppQualifier" />
                        <asp:DynamicField DataField="FootNote" HeaderText="FootNote" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Delivery" DataField="Delivery" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ListPrice" DataField="ListPrice" 
                            DataFormatString="&quot;{0:c}&quot;" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="YourPrice" DataField="YourPrice" 
                            DataFormatString="&quot;{0:c}&quot;" ReadOnly="True" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Add 1" CommandName="cmdAdd1" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="QtyPurch" DataField="QtyPurch" />
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Remove 1" CommandName="cmdRemove1" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>


                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ABCWebConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="GetApplicationProductsSelected" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="WeborderNumber" SessionField="Session(&quot;WebOrderNumber&quot;)" Type="Int64" DbType="Int64" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Code behind is
{

Partial Public Class _AppProdsSelect
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Public Event RowCommand As GridViewCommandEventHandler
'Public Event ShadowsPreRender As EventHandler

Dim bBeenHereAdd1 As Boolean, bBeenHereRemove1 As Boolean, bBeenHereDetails As Boolean, bBeen2cmdCompare0 As Boolean
Dim sProdCode As String, sDelivery As String = ""
Protected WithEvents cmdMake As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
Protected WithEvents cmdModel As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
Protected WithEvents cmdYear As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
Protected WithEvents cmdEngine As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
Protected WithEvents GridView1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
Protected WithEvents Label2 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label
Dim liCartCount As Integer

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim GridView1 As New GridView

    'Dim licount As Int32, sListPrice As String              '   , sYourPrice As String
    If Session("UserID") = "" Then
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
    End If
    Session("LastForm") = "AppProdsSelect.aspx"
    If Not IsPostBack _
    And Not IsNothing(Session("Make")) _
    And Not IsNothing(Session("Model")) _
    And Not IsNothing(Session("Year")) _
    And Not IsNothing(Session("Engine")) Then
        Me.cmdMake.Text = Session("Make").ToString
        Me.cmdModel.Text = Session("Model").ToString
        Me.cmdYear.Text = Session("Year").ToString
        Me.cmdEngine.Text = Session("Engine").ToString
    End If


    'Dim bSuccessful As Boolean
    'Dim conn As New SqlConnection(), myReader As SqlDataReader
    'Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    'Dim SqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    'SqlCon.ConnectionString = constr
    'SqlCon.Open()
    'Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    'Dim sSQl As String
    'sSQl = "SELECT  [ID], [WebOrderNum],[XRefKey],[ProductCodeStocking],[AppQualifier]"
    'sSQl = sSQl & ",[FootNote],[Product],[ListPrice],[WarehouseCodeStocking],[YourPrice]"
    'sSQl = sSQl & ",[QtyPurch],[Delivery],[ChooseMe] ,[ExtAmount],[ApplicationNum],[ImageName]"
    'sSQl = sSQl & ",[Make],[Model],[Year],[Engine]"
    'sSQl = sSQl & " FROM([ABCWeb].[dbo].[AppProdsSelect])"
    'sSQl = sSQl & " Where [WebOrderNum]  " = Session("WebOrderNumber")

    'cmd.Connection = SqlCon
    'cmd.CommandText = sSQl
    'Dim oDataAdapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    'Dim ds As New DataSet
    'oDataAdapter.Fill(ds)

    'GridView1.DataBind()
    'GridView1.DataSource = ds
    'GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub



Protected Sub cmdMake_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdMake.Click
    Session("Lookup2Show") = "Make"
    Response.Redirect("MakeLookup.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdModel_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdModel.Click
    Session("Lookup2Show") = "Model"
    Response.Redirect("MakeLookup.aspx")
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdYear_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdYear.Click
    Session("Lookup2Show") = "Year"
    Response.Redirect("MakeLookup.aspx", False)
End Sub

Protected Sub cmdEngine_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdEngine.Click
    Session("Lookup2Show") = "Engine"
    Response.Redirect("MakeLookup.aspx")
End Sub
```

End Class

}

Comment: `ecommerce website` in `vb.net`? Are you doing a desktop application or web application? Also please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use the wrong grid control for the application type. In addition, whichever type of application you use, I find it hard to believe that any grid control would… _“only work with data bound rows”_ … I suggest you take a closer look at the grid control that is available for the project type. I am confident it will allow you to add rows without using a data source.

Comment: The `DataGridView` control is strictly for WinForms. If you are currently using a standard `GridView` control then you are presumably creating an ASP.NET Web Forms project. `DataGridView` is not an option. In that case, please explain why you can't bind your data? The user can still add rows to the grid in the UI when it's bound. I suspect that you absolutely could bind your data but you just don't know how to do it properly.

Comment: I have added more detail. I hope you can tell me what I am doing improperly - Ed